# Add My public IP to a VPN setup in UK

Tags: server, ip-address, vpn

I have a server in India office with Public IP address allocated to it. For our UK client we would like to use UK IP address, In our UK office we have VPN setup and there is also a unique VPN out IP. I would like to add my server in that network so that my IP is allocated the out IP of UK. Can any one help me on this.

> - My present IP for eg. 101.101.1.0
> - My UK Office VPN IP is eg: 110.102.1.0

Please let me know if we can do it any artificial with reference will be a great help. Thanks in advance...

The main objective of this is:

The purpose is some of the work the UK clients white list only UK IP address they doesn't allow Indian IP to work on; that is the reason why i we need to work on the UK IP based server. we have a UK server working remotely is really pain but if we have a server here which we can connect and work locally really helps us.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so?   For performance?  So search engines know the country of the website?  It matters because you will get different answers for different purposes.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide clarification and we will re-open it.

Comment: The purpose is some of the work the UK clients white list only UK IP address they doesn't allow Indian IP to work on that is the reason why i we need to work on the UK IP based server. we have a UK server working remotely is really pain but if we have a server here which we can connect and work locally really helps us.